# Use users time without converting to UTC in params in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I am working on rails application where user can send the time when he wants notification.

Scenario: Take an example use in India(+05:30) time zone. But in rails params it's automatically converted to **UTC**.

User selected time from **date time picker**:

```
Wed, 06 Apr 2017 04:00:00 #(no option to select timezone)
```

In Rails params:

```
"2017-04-05 22:30:00 UTC"
```

But I want to save same time which user selected but it could in **UTC**

```
"2017-04-06 04:00:00 UTC"
```

Is there any **Rails configuration** or method by which I can achieve this?

Comment: You might wanna change the applications time zone

Comment: Get your country timezone from here:-  rake time:zones:all then add it in application.rb,
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)',
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Answer (score 0):

First run to see all available timezone

```
bundle exec rake time:zones:all
```

than after

```
change Inside config/application.rb 
config.time_zone = "UTC"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

Here you can choose any timezone